# Make a population figure in R/R Markdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

I want to move my article writing exclusively to R Markdown.
Is there a way to build study population figure like this one:
[image]

Comment: The [Diagrammer package](http://rich-iannone.github.io/DiagrammeR/docs.html) may be useful for this use case. Even better: [the PRISMAstatement package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/PRISMAstatement/vignettes/PRISMA.html).

Answer (score 0):

As a complete graphics novice I was unaware of the amazing DiagrammeR packege, which I am now starting to learn further.

In the meanwhile after installing it I was able to achieve my goal quite simply by Modifying an example from @Artem Sokolov:

```
    grViz("digraph flowchart {
      node [fontname = Helvetica, shape = rectangle, fixedsize = false, width = 1]
      1 [label = 'Initial Cohort - ']
      2 [label = 'Left After Reduction - ']
      3 [label = 'Group 1']
      4 [label = 'Group 2']
      5 [label = 'Group 3']
      m1 [label = 'Excluded: \\l -Reason 1 - X \\l -Reason 2 - Y']
      node [shape=none, width=0, height=0, label='']
      p1 -> 2;
      {rank=same; p1 -> m1}
    
      edge [dir=none]
      1 -> p1;
      2 -> 3
      2 -> 4
      2 -> 5
    }")
```

Creating this Chart:

[image]